# Discussion questions that are not "I have one very specific problem with one very specific answer"

Tags: discussion

Are general discussion threads allowed or frowned upon?  What I mean is what if I'm going down a certain implementation route that doesn't have a right or wrong answer?  Is it ok to post asking "how do you handle these situations?" to get a feel for other alternatives?

Specifically I was going to add a post about asking how people work with mysql partitioning and what kind of managment and automation they have in place for that.

I had seen other threads that seemed to be "survey" threads like that only to get closed down for being 'inappropriate'.

Answer (score 3):

Generally I suggest reading this section of the /faq

https://dba.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask

If you feel, after reading that section of the FAQ, that

1. Your question **avoids those common pitfalls** (and oh boy are they common)
2. Your peers can **learn something constructive and useful from your question**

Then I say go for it.

Comment: Really it was along the template to avoid of "# your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”"  At the same time I don't get why that's undesirable.  It's seeking knoweldge and experience from others that might have other/better solutions.  C'est le vie, I'll take my general discussions elsewhere.

Comment: @atxdba http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/ I still have trouble understanding the distinction on the SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

Are you discussing architectural designs? Do you want someone to check your code and make sure it's sane? Is it about databases or in general?

For discussing the architecture of your database, this site is fine for that.

For discussing the architecture of your app, you might consider asking on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

For getting another set of eyes on your code, check into http://codereview.stackexchange.com